# Почему зависает поток внутри выключенного ExecutorService?

Tags: java, многопоточность

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    service.submit(
            () -> {
                System.out.println("start");
                while (true) {
                    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        System.out.println("I am interrupted");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("I am not interrupted");
                    }
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);
                        System.out.println("I am not sleeping");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("task interrupted");
                      //  throw e; //если не пробросить то поток будет продолжать работать
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("end");
            }
    );

    service.shutdown();
    try {
        service.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("main thread interrupted");
    } finally {
        if (!service.isTerminated()) {
            System.out.println("service is not terminated");
            service.shutdownNow();  //однако если поток сам ловит InterruptedException и их поглощает - то поток не остановится
        } else {
            System.out.println("service is terminated");
        }
        System.out.println("end finally");
    }

    System.out.println("end main " + service.isShutdown());
}
```

Получается, что ExecutorService как бы выключен - но один из тредов, который в нем был запущен, продолжает работу. Почему такое допустимо - работающий поток и service.isShutdown()==true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что поток ловит `InterruptedException` не говорит о том, что флаг `isInterrupted()` становится `true`. Поток вего лишь просят корректно завершить работу, а вы уже должны принять решение, как это сделать и когда. И когда вы это сделаете, то устанавливаете этот флаг внутри потока через `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` - в вашем случае в `catch` секции вместо `throw e`.

При этом для контроля, что все потоки сервиса завершили свою работу, необходимо использовать метод `isTerminated()`а не `isShutdown()` (который сигнализирует о прекращении приёма новых потоков).

Comment: вопрос не в том что флаг поглощается самим потоком - а в том почему ExecutorService позволяет себя выключить и считает себя выключенным при том что потоки внутри него не остановлены.

Comment: Вы наверное путаете isShutdown() и isTerminated(). Первое - был вызван shutdown() и не принимаются новые потоки. Второе - все работающие потоки в сервисе остановились.

Comment: да - похоже Вы правы - можете добавить это в свой ответ про isShutdown() и isTerminated() ?